# Converting a datetime column with UTC timezone to another TimeZone based on a column of the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dateframe which has two columns, with column names 'DateTimeInUTC' and 'TimeZone'. 'DateTimeInUTC' is the date and time of the instance in UTC, and 'TimeZone' is the time zone of the location of the instance.

An instance in the dataframe could be like this:

```
DateTimeInUTC: '2019-12-31 07:00:00'
TimeZone: 'US/Eastern'
```

I want to add another column to the dataframe with dType: datetime64 which converts 'DateTimeInUTC' to the specified time zone in that instance.

---

I tried using the method `Pandas.tz_convert()` but it takes the timezone as an argument and not as another column in the dataframe

---

EDIT: My best solution so far is to split the dataframe by timezone using pandas select statements and then apply the timezone on each dataframe with the same timezone, and then concatenate all the dataframes

Comment: Can you add some sample code? Would be easier for prototyping for others.

Comment: @Ron I added a sample code as a potential answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach with `groupby()`:

```
import pytz
import random
import time

tic = time.perf_counter()
ltz = len(pytz.all_timezones) - 1
length = 7 * 10 ** 6
pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None
# generate the dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTimeInUTC': pd.date_range('01.01.2000', periods=length, freq='T', tz='UTC'),
                   'TimeZone': [pytz.all_timezones[random.randint(0, ltz)] for tz in range(length)]})

toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Generated the df in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds\n")

tic = time.perf_counter()

df['Converted'] = df.groupby('TimeZone')['DateTimeInUTC'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.tz_convert(x.name).dt.tz_localize(None))

print(df)

toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"\nConverted the df in {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
```

Output:

```
Generated the df in 6.3333 seconds

                    DateTimeInUTC            TimeZone           Converted
0       2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00      Asia/Qyzylorda 2000-01-01 05:00:00
1       2000-01-01 00:01:00+00:00     America/Moncton 1999-12-31 20:01:00
2       2000-01-01 00:02:00+00:00     America/Cordoba 1999-12-31 21:02:00
3       2000-01-01 00:03:00+00:00        Africa/Dakar 2000-01-01 00:03:00
4       2000-01-01 00:04:00+00:00      Pacific/Wallis 2000-01-01 12:04:00
...                           ...                 ...                 ...
6999995 2013-04-23 02:35:00+00:00      America/Guyana 2013-04-22 22:35:00
6999996 2013-04-23 02:36:00+00:00  America/St_Vincent 2013-04-22 22:36:00
6999997 2013-04-23 02:37:00+00:00             MST7MDT 2013-04-22 20:37:00
6999998 2013-04-23 02:38:00+00:00  Antarctica/McMurdo 2013-04-23 14:38:00
6999999 2013-04-23 02:39:00+00:00    America/Atikokan 2013-04-22 21:39:00

[7000000 rows x 3 columns]

Converted the df in 4.1579 seconds
```

Comment: The result should be different for each timezone, hence the conversion. In the above output section, the times are all still 07:00:00 for the TZ-aware column. Also, the DateTimeInUTC is already timezone-aware, but the timezone is in UTC.

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Comment: In the second edit, the times are converted, but 07:00:00 UTC should be around 02:00:00 EST and not 12:00:00. I think the order of tz_localize and tz_convert is wrong. First it should be localized by UTC, (in this case, my dataframe is already timezone aware) and then converted to the new timezone, instead of converting to UTC.

Comment: See the current edition

Comment: I tried to run it on my dataframe which has 7 million instances, and it literally crashed the python compiler!! I think it would be a lot more efficient if I split my dataframe by timezone, and then applied the timezone conversion on each part and then concatenate the whole think.

Comment: I implemented your idea of processing by grouped time zones using `groupby()`. On my machine, 7M rows work in 4.2 seconds

Comment: I was able to get my own solution to around 3 seconds as well. I'll keep your answer as the accepted answer though ;)

Comment: @Ahmad I think the running time of your solution is highly dependent on the number of timezones in the sample. On the data generated in my example with 593 time zones, your code ran on my machine in 193.7 seconds

Comment: You are correct, I only had 4 timezones

Answer (score 2):

**The Better solution:**

I was able to improve my own solution substantially:

```
timezones = weatherDf['TimeZone'].unique()
for timezone in timezones:
    weatherDf.loc[weatherDf['TimeZone'] == timezone, 'DateTimeInTimeZone'] = weatherDf.loc[weatherDf['TimeZone'] == timezone, 'DateTimeInUTC'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(timezone).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

This solution converted around 7 million instances on my system in 3.6 seconds

---

**My previous solution:**

This solution works, but it is probably not optimal:

let's assume weatherDf is my dataframe, which has these columns: `DateTimeInUTC` and `TimeZone`

```
timezones = weatherDf['TimeZone'].unique()
weatherDfs = []
for timezone in timezones:
    tempDf = weatherDf[weatherDf['TimeZone'] == timezone]
    tempDf['DateTimeInTimeZone'] = tempDf['DateTimeInUTC'].dt.tz_convert(timezone)
    weatherDfs.append(tempDf)
weatherDfConverted = pd.concat(weatherDfs)
```

This solution converted around 7 million instances on my system in around 40 seconds